# Is there better approach for partitioning list and process in batches for changing source list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I will have a source list which is basically dynamic in nature. Some process will keep continuously adding records to this source list. I would like to process the record in this list as batches of say 10 entries. Once the entries are processed, it has be cleared from the source list so that I don't process them again and make sure the list doesn't grow.

I would also like not to block the source list for long to add records.(say we do something in sync block). Can someone help to solve this problem in an efficient way ?

I am planning to use Guava list partition to get the records in batches, but I don't understand if this works on continuously changing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is simple example to partitioning list and process the elements of size 10.
After 10 element it will clear the list and again you can fill new elements in same list.
In your batches process you can use this code to clear the record after specific size of list elements.

```
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = null;
        Scanner scan = null;
        char choice = 'n';
        try {
            arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter 10 element and add in ArrayList");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter element [" +i+"] :: ");
                    int number = scan.nextInt();
                    arrList.add(number);
                }

                for (Integer number : arrList) {
                    System.out.println("Elements in list = " + number);
                }
                int retval = arrList.size();
                if (retval == 10) {
                    arrList.clear();
                }
                System.out.println("Performing clear operation !!");
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue !!");
                String next = scan.next();
                choice = next.charAt(0);
            } while ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y'));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            scan.close();
            System.out.println("Exit  !!");
        }
    }
```

**Output :**

```
Enter 10 element and add in ArrayList

Enter element [0] :: 1

Enter element [1] :: 2

Enter element [2] :: 3

Enter element [3] :: 4

Enter element [4] :: 5

Enter element [5] :: 6

Enter element [6] :: 7

Enter element [7] :: 8

Enter element [8] :: 9

Enter element [9] :: 10

Elements in list = 1

Elements in list = 2

Elements in list = 3

Elements in list = 4

Elements in list = 5

Elements in list = 6

Elements in list = 7

Elements in list = 8

Elements in list = 9

Elements in list = 10

Performing clear operation !!

Do you want to continue !!

N

Exit  !!
```

You can change this code as par your requirement.

Hope this example is helpful to you.